# How do I create a dynamic "About Me" page in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Here, by dynamic I mean, I wouldn't want to update my template in order for me to update changes. I'd want them to edit in the admin page on my production site. At first, I thought I'd create a model for "About Me" itself, but then I'd need to create a model for just one instance.

I need help with this, better ways to edit my pages dynamically on the admin site.

Comment: And you're planning to not use django admin site, right?

Comment: I'd want to use the django admin site.

Comment: Okay, I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a model for **About Me** as you mentioned. Since you've highlighted that you would want to work with the `django admin site`, then what you could do is to set the permission for only one object to be created for that model which can be updated whenever.

For example:

`models.py` file.

```
class AboutMe(models.Model):
     # With the desired fields of your choice
```

Now you can set the permission within the `admin.py` file to only allow one instance from the model to be created.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import AboutMe

MAX_OBJECTS = 1

# Using decorator here
@admin.register(AboutMe)
class AboutMeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fields = ['..', '..', '..'] # fields you want to display on the forms
     list_display = ['..', '..', '..'] # fields you want to display on the page for list on objects

     # Allowing the user to only add one object for this model...
     def has_add_permission(self, request):
          if self.model.objects.count() >= MAX_OBJECTS:
               return False
          return super().has_add_permission(request)
```

That should be a nice fit for your situation. Also, you can read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/) to learn more about customizing `django admin site`.